# Create custom Angular filter that returns an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, filter

Is there a way to create a [custom angular filter function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) that returns an object?

I understand from the documentation that filter: can take an object as the expression. For example, the following will only objects with the name Neil Diamond:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in collection | filter:{'name':'Neil Diamond'}">
```

I was trying to filter a dynamic object. I created a function that builds the object and returns it, but that isn't working. Is this an innapropriate approach to achieve my goal?

### HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeAudience('Clinicians')" /> Clinicians
<br>
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeAudience('ElderlyVeterans')" /> ElderlyVeterans
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="resource in resources | filter:audienceFilter">
    {{resource.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Javascript

```
  $scope.resources = [{
    'name': 'Resource 1',
    'ElderlyVeterans': false,
    'Clinicians': true
  }, {
    'name': 'Resource 2',
    'ElderlyVeterans': true,
    'Clinicians': false
  }];

  $scope.audienceIncludes = [];

  $scope.includeAudience = function(resource) {
    var i = $.inArray(colour, $scope.audienceIncludes);
    if (i > -1) {
      $scope.audienceIncludes.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
      $scope.audienceIncludes.push(resource);
    }
  }

  $scope.audienceFilter = function(resource) {
    if ($scope.audienceIncludes.length > 0) {
      $scope.audiencesShown = {};
      angular.forEach($scope.audienceIncludes, function(audience) {
        $scope.audiencesShown[audience] = true;
      });
      return $scope.audiencesShown;
    }
    return resource;
  }
});
```

You can see the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/matthew_nahmias/5oqda19n/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your are giving the function as a raw object. This means angular will treat the function itself as a filter, not the result of it. You should evaluate the function, like this :

```
<li ng-repeat="resource in resources | filter:audienceFilter()">
  {{resource.name}}
</li>
```

(I added parenthesis after `audienceFilter`).

This seems to work in the jsfiddle at least.